# In the Absalom Initiation adventure, should PCs be assigned quests from all 4 districts?

Tags: published-adventures, pathfinder-society, pathfinder-2e

The [Absalom Initiation](https://paizo.com/products/btq01znb?Pathfinder-Society-Scenario-101-The-Absalom-Initiation) is a replayable Pathfinder Society adventure.  The players start off at a party where:

> they must talk to 4 faction leaders to be assigned 4 different quests in 4 different regions.

However:

> Quests are randomly assigned from a table. When I rolled the random quests, two of the quests were to take place in the same region - meaning that the PCs only needed to visit 3 of the 4 regions in the adventure.

This is fine and all, but:

> The last region contains 2 treasure bundles. Without it, the PCs can gain a maximum of 8 bundles. It feels like an unfair limit because it's a random event, not something the players can deal with.

This will be the first Pathfinder Society event I have GMed. Is there something I am missing in the adventure? If not, how should I handle this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make only one roll on the random quest table, then read across for the location of each of the quests. It's designed so that each of the four locations is used once. So, if you roll a 1, Faction leader 1 gives the quest for location A, 2 for B, 3 for C, 4 for D (all four location used), but if you roll a 2, those locations are changed up e.g. 1->B, 2->C, 3->D, 4->A.

Some combinations aren't used - the first faction leader will never give a quest for the fourth location.

There are nine combinations possible; on a roll of a 10 you roll again.

That way, the party will always visit all four locations, but the quests they have at each are randomly determined.

Comment: Note that you don't strictly have to roll - if for example some of these players have already played the arrangement on row 4, it's perfectly alright to select a different row so that things will be fresh. But yes, you should use the entire row.